# How to fetch the next value instead of only the 1st one - Vlookup Importrange - google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

CONTEXT

- I have 2 tabs in a google spreadsheet that are connected with Vlookup and Importange
- Both sheets have "ID" and "Payment Ref" columns
- The goal is by Adding an "ID" value, the other column fetches from the other sheet its payment ref

PROBLEM

- All works fine EXCEPT when an ID has multiple payment refs it always shows the first value / the first payment ref related to that ID

RESULT

- I would like that it would fetch the next payment ref related to that ID instead of always showing the same

Thank you in advance

[Example google sheet - simplified](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VDm6tNlD47Fe1pnQC7dBNJA0mtrqFSSI3wYh-4KyyUs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround, not sure if it is the best one, but if I create an helper column that adds to the ID value a counter (the nr of times the value appears) by using the "count" function, the vlookup can search for all matches.

e.g.

```
=A2&"-"&COUNTIF($A$2:A2;A2)
```

(Also added in the example sheet)

Unfortunately adding "Arrayformula" doesn't create an array and I need to stretch the formula along the rows.

Not perfect but if nothing better, hope it helps others.